# From iCal to JSON then to a HTML/jQuery Calendar View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, icalendar

I've successfully converted an ICS file (iCalendar) to jSON:

```
{
  "vcalendar": [
    {
      "method": "PUBLISH",
      "prodid": "Microsoft Exchange Server 2010",
      "version": "2.0",
      "x-wr-calname": "Website",
      "vtimezone": [
        {
          "tzid": "GMT Standard Time",
          "standard": [
            {
              "dtstart": "16010101T020000",
              "tzoffsetfrom": "+0100",
              "tzoffsetto": "+0000",
              "rrule": "FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10"
            }
          ],
          "daylight": [
            {
              "dtstart": "16010101T010000",
              "tzoffsetfrom": "+0000",
              "tzoffsetto": "+0100",
              "rrule": {
                "freq": "YEARLY",
                "interval": "1",
                "byday": "-1SU",
                "bymonth": "3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "vevent": [
        {
          "summary": "test event",
          "dtstart": [
            "20140624T140000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "dtend": [
            "20140624T150000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "uid": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000AA6D0AFA958FCF0100000000000000001000000054D58145BFBC024DB6FFCA2E760D16C4",
          "class": "PUBLIC",
          "priority": "5",
          "dtstamp": "20140717T105947Z",
          "transp": "OPAQUE",
          "status": "CONFIRMED",
          "sequence": "0",
          "location": "",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-appt-sequence": "0",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-busystatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-intendedstatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-alldayevent": "FALSE",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-importance": "1",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-insttype": "0",
          "x-microsoft-disallow-counter": "FALSE"
        },
        {
          "description": "Test\\n",
          "summary": "Test Event 1",
          "dtstart": [
            "20140709T150000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "dtend": [
            "20140709T160000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "uid": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000C1F07C325A9BCF010000000000000000100000007DA6DF5B9E26DD40BFA577BFC9833825",
          "class": "PUBLIC",
          "priority": "5",
          "dtstamp": "20140717T105947Z",
          "transp": "OPAQUE",
          "status": "CONFIRMED",
          "sequence": "0",
          "location": "",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-appt-sequence": "0",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-busystatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-intendedstatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-alldayevent": "FALSE",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-importance": "1",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-insttype": "0",
          "x-microsoft-disallow-counter": "FALSE"
        },
        {
          "description": "\\n",
          "summary": "Test Event 2",
          "dtstart": [
            "20140710T110000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "dtend": [
            "20140710T120000",
            {
              "tzid": "GMT Standard Time"
            }
          ],
          "uid": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000080863A5A9BCF01000000000000000010000000532737AA9F20CD479A2B424CBB66F0F6",
          "class": "PUBLIC",
          "priority": "5",
          "dtstamp": "20140717T105947Z",
          "transp": "OPAQUE",
          "status": "CONFIRMED",
          "sequence": "0",
          "location": "",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-appt-sequence": "0",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-busystatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-intendedstatus": "BUSY",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-alldayevent": "FALSE",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-importance": "1",
          "x-microsoft-cdo-insttype": "0",
          "x-microsoft-disallow-counter": "FALSE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to parse jSON so that I can create a calendar view, like this parses an ics file and displays a calendar view http://www.instantcal.com/isc/js/cvu.html.

How do I loop through vevents so that I can create a simple list of all the events, and the days they start?

Comment: You can use plugins like this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar this, it will do all you need for calendar

Comment: @RajAdroit It doesn't look like it supports iCalendar, I'll have to write my own extension, which I won't know how to do as I'm not a Javascript guru.

Comment: yes, i can see your converted iCal to json, and just pass that json object to fullcalendar, it will do displaying those things properly

Comment: @RajAdroit I've successfully imported fullcalendar into rails, and got the calendar displaying. How do I pass the json into fullcalendar? I don't understand this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: you can try like this $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events); , events is a json object

Comment: @RajAdroit Sorry, I don't understand. `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', '../calendars.json');` doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57493/discussion-between-taylor-williams-and-raj-adroit).